# entity framework create history tables for entities

Tags: entity-framework-4

We would like to create a history table for each of our entities.
Is there a way to have entity framework create the history entities/tables automatically, given the existing entities?

For example, the `Customer` entity would have a shadow history table called `CustomerHistory`.  Whenever there is an edit or a delete, the old record will be inserted into the history table.   The main entity table will always contain the current record.

Since we have several entities, I would rather not have to create a separate history entity and repository for each entity, thus doubling the entities.

We would like to do this for all of our entities in order to track transactional and state temporal changes to the entities.

We use the unit of work and repository patterns.

Assume that the properties of the Entity and the `EntityHistory` objects would be the same, although we may want to extend the history object with some datetime properties.

I understand how to [override `DbContext.SaveChanges` in order to write to history/audit tables](http://jmdority.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/using-entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-change-tracking-for-audit-logging/).

What I want to avoid doing is having to create duplicate history entities/repositories for every entity that we have.

I am currently exploring doing something in `OnModelCreating` to create a history entity for each entity  but have not found a good example.

Any ideas?

Comment: I actually created separate entities, though they share a common interface to keep the properties synced. Having separate entities makes it easier to query on. And i found i didn't want to create a history for every single entity i use. So in the end it wasn't that hard to do. I use Code First EF 4.3.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jeroen.  We are using Code First EF 5.0.  We will probably go the same route if there are no better ideas.

Comment: I'm currently looking for a solution to a similar need. I was thinking of leaving it out of scope for EF and use database triggers. Is this something you guys considered too ? If so, why didn't you choose it in the end ? The one reason I could think of is that you wouldn't be able to query them as entites with EF...